# write to EXI format xml on ipad

Tags: ios, xml, gdataxml, exi

I have a requirement to read and write xml files in w3c format on an ipad app. In my previous app I read basic xml files using GDataXML and that worked exactly as I needed. Can I use the same GDataXML to read and write xml files in w3c format aswell?, or do I need a different class?

edit: The format I need to read and write to is [Efficient XML Interchange (EXI)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-exi-20110310/).

Comment: Do you have any details of what "w3c format" means in this context? XML itself is a format defined by the w3c, so *all* XML is in their format, in that sense.

Comment: sorry, here is a link to the format that the xml files will be in.
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-exi-20110310/

Comment: Ah, I see. You should probably edit your question to mention that format, as that's actually quite a different format from XML itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, neither Apple nor Google has done anything related to EXI in their products, and the only choice available on iOS at this point appears to be a commercial product from AgileDelta [1].
[1] http://www.agiledelta.com/product_efxsdk.html

Comment: I wasnt able to find anything else either. I was hoping for something opensource that was able to do this. The only thing I found was exip which is built for c. I would try to make it work with xcode, but I dont have the time. I will mark this as the answer, but if anyone wants, the link for exip is http://exip.sourceforge.net/